# Role-Based Access Control to a User

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity, user-roles

I have an application MVC 4.0 using Entity Framework.

I have a USER table, Role table, Type table.

Role can be out of the two: `Administrator`, `User`

Type can be out of 8: None, `Admin, Asst.Admin, ......`

So I want to allow different pages to be accessed based on the type as below:

1) Types defined:

```
None    Con     Acc     Rec     St      Fr      Admin  AsAd  ( <-- Types)
----------------------------------------------------------
```

1.a) Update client:

```
None    None    None    None    Edit    View    Full  Full  ( <-- Roles)
```

1.b) New Client:

```
None    None    None    View    View    Edit    Full  Full  ( <-- Roles)
```

So how will this be achieved ?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? have you attempted anything ? Have youi googled ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with an AuthorizeAttribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class ActionPermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
```

Add this attribute to all the Actions you need to have authorised - add at the controller makes this easier or even create a base controller that inherits `Controller` and then inherit all your controllers from that.

You can then store your controller+action vs role in the DB

```
        // get allowed groups for this controller+action from the database (cache this)
        // get which AD groups the current user is in (or get from the DB etc)
        var userGroups = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Groups
                         .Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount))
        // check if user in in required group
```

If you really want to have permissions defined in code per action, then just add properties to the attribute and attribute constructor as required.

I didn't fully understand your role vs type, but in MVC everything is an action (method) so you lock down individual actions (there's no 'edit' just an action called 'edit').